# ServiceStack Redis v4.0.52 IRedisClient.Db setter not working as expected

Tags: servicestack.redis

We recently upgraded the ServiceStack DLLs in our project from version 4.0.38 to version 4.0.52. We are making a call like this:

```
var clientManager = new BasicRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1");
var client = clientManager.GetClient();
client.Db = 3; // set the DB to 3
var item = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
client.AddItemToList("test_q", item);
```

In version 4.0.38 this call correctly resulted in an item in the `test_q` list in DB 3 (`select 3`). However when we upgraded to version 4.0.52 the setting of the DB to 3 no longer works and the item ends up in the default DB 0.

Is this a bug or is there a change in the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a change in behavior that's now resolved [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/29c3d0167c0e296713c09527b0707e2e5bd29a76) which is due to `GetClient()` now returning an already connected client. This change is available from v4.0.53 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

One way to force a Database change to an already connected client is to use the explicit `ChangeDb()` API, e.g:

```
((RedisClient)client).ChangeDb(3);
```

Another option is to specify the Db in the connection string, e.g:

```
var clientManager = new BasicRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1?db=3");
```